# Converting Perl Regex to PHP

Tags: php, regex, perl

I have the following Regex in PERL which I need to convert to PHP

```
if($line =~ m/[<]div class="row.* id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})"[>]/i){ }
```

I currently have the following in PHP to match it, but I'm not getting the same results:

```
preg_grep('/[<]div class="row(.*) id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})"[>]/', $lines);
```

Can anyone tell me if what I have is the same or if I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preg_grep`](https://www.php.net/preg_grep) returns an array whereas if you use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match), you get a boolean. So if you are using:

```
if($line =~ m/[<]div class="row.* id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})"[>]/i){ }
```

It would be an equivalent for:

```
if(preg_match('/[<]div class="row(.*) id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})"[>]/i', $line)) { };
```

Though you can simplify the regex a bit:

```
if(preg_match('/<div class="row(.*) id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})">/i', $line)) { };
```

---

If you want to see the matches, you could do:

```
if(preg_match('/<div class="row(.*) id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})">/i', $line, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
};
```

Comment: Hey thanku so much.. But could you help me to display the matches?

Comment: @user3428183 Added that in my answer.

Comment: Thanku. But an error $line should be a string. In my case its an array.

Comment: I got it now. Thanx. There are multiple lines and its displaying only the 1st line. How do I match it for all the lines?

Comment: @user3428183 You change `preg_match` to `preg_match_all` and the procedure is the same otherwise. Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192545) :)

Comment: Hey listen. I have 1 more query. I want to display only the id's and not the classes in the above match. Can you help?

Comment: @user3428183 Hmm a more correct way would be to use this regex then: `/<div class="row.*? id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})">/i` That means you will get the ID in the first element of the array `$match` (or first sub-element if you have many matches).

Comment: Awesome. I got the exact result I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey any idea how to insert these values into mysql database?

Comment: @user3428183 Sorry, I'm not familiar with that :( You could maybe see if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17723727/1578604) gives you some clues?

Comment: That's really ok. I got it:)

Answer (score 0):

- Append `i` [Pattern Modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the pattern
- Use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to return true or false

Sample code:

```
if (preg_match('/[<]div class="row(.*) id="(vm_[0-9]{8,9})"[>]/i', $lines)) {

  echo "A match was found.";

}
```

Comment: Hey thanku so much.. But could you help me to display the matches?